# How to use pd.cut in pandas

Tags: pandas

Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't working:

```
ages = ['15-19','20-24','25-29','30-34','35-39','40-44','45-49','50-54','55-59','60-64','65-69','70-74','75-79','80-84']

race['age_group'] = pd.cut(race.Age,range(13,84,5),right=False, labels=ages)

race[['Age','age_group']].head(15)
```

This is the result I get:

```
        Age age_group
    0   31  30-34
    1   38  40-44
    2   45  45-49
    3   30  30-34
    4   45  45-49
    5   35  35-39
    6   32  30-34
    7   33  35-39
    8   29  30-34
    9   42  40-44
   10   34  35-39
   11   48  50-54
   12   35  35-39
   13   51  50-54
   14   38  40-44
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your "range" is not correct, try:

```
ages = ['15-19','20-24','25-29','30-34','35-39','40-44','45-49','50-54','55-59','60-64','65-69','70-74','75-79','80-84']
race['age_group'] = pd.cut(race.Age,range(15,86,5),right=False, labels=ages)
race[['Age','age_group']].head(15)
```

Comment: Thanks that works great. I think I understand starting the range at 15, but I don't understand ending at 86?

Comment: Ending of the range is exclusive, it doesn't include the last number.  Inorder, to get 85, you must end your range at 86.   https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Comment: You are going in steps of 5, therefore you need to include 85 in your last bin range.